# ALTER TABLE con columna nueva que sea foreign key MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito agregar una columna nueva en una de mis tablas, pero esta columna a su vez es una foreign key de otra tabla pero no sé como hacerlo...

He intentado esto pero evidentemente me ha dado error:

```
ALTER TABLE ordenes ADD COLUMN ticket varchar(50) FOREIGN KEY (ticket) REFERENCES tickets(ticket)
```

Comment: ¿cuál es el error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primero añade sólo la columna y luego la fk:

```
ALTER TABLE ordenes ADD ticket VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE ordenes ADD CONSTRAINT fk_ticket FOREIGN KEY (ticket) REFERENCES tickets(ticket);
```

En la tabla tickets sería mejor llamarlo "algo" + id en lugar de "ticket".
Recuerda que tiene que ser un campo único.

Comment: Suelo utilizar esa técnica ppor ejemplo ticket_id, pero el problema es que estoy trabajando sobre una base de datos que ya fue creada en su momento, con nombres en castellano, columnas llamadas como les da la gana y un largo etc de cosas, con lo cual solo intento arreglar por mi parte lo que puedo y quizas con el tiempo y si me contratan para más tiempo ponerme manos a la obra e intentar "arreglar" esa base de datos.

Answer (score 2):

La sintaxis que estás utilizando no es soportada por mysql. Agrega la columna y el constraint por separado, esto funcionará en la gran mayoría de motores, no solo MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE ordenes ADD COLUMN ticket varchar(50);
ALTER TABLE ordenes ADD constraint FK_Ordenes_Tickets FOREIGN KEY (ticket) REFERENCES tickets(ticket)
```

He añadido un nombre al constraint, pero podrías obviar esa parte.