# ¿Cómo copiar una llave foránea a otra tabla diferente?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla llamada tbl_usuarios relacionada a través de una llave foránea a una tabla llamada tbl_departamentos... quisiera copiar la llave foranea de tbl_departamentos a una tabla diferente llamada tbl_copia y que esta nueva tabla mantenga relación con tbl_usuarios a través de la misma llave foránea copiada.

Este es un ejemplo de mis tablas y lo que quisiera obtener:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando SQL.

Comment: Esa relación la puedes crear con `ALTER TABLE tbl_copia ADD CONSTRAINT ...`   [mira un ejemplo aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/32316/29967). Ver también [el MR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [ALTER TABLE con columna nueva que sea foreign key MYSQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32312/alter-table-con-columna-nueva-que-sea-foreign-key-mysql)

Comment: no... porque estoy trabajando con mucha información... y esa columna quisiera copiarla tal cual junto con toda su información  en una tabla completamente a parte... que haga la misma relación que mi otra tabla

Answer (score 0):

-- MYSQL, en la tabla `conductor`, digo que `co_c_id`  será la llave foranea y esta viene relacionada desde la tabla `cliente` en la columna `c_id`

```
ALTER TABLE conductor
 ADD FOREIGN KEY co_c_idFK (co_c_id) REFERENCES cliente (c_id);
```